# Autodesk Forge on AWS : Error (https://aws-quickstart.s3.amazonaws.com/quickstart-autodesk-forge/templates/autodesk-forge-master.json)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, autodesk-forge

I am trying to host my Autodesk Forge model on AWS, in the process of creating the stack, there is this error **(https://aws-quickstart.s3.amazonaws.com/quickstart-autodesk-forge/templates/autodesk-forge-master.json)**
I just found this error shows that the file does not exist.

1. How can I solve this problem?
2. How can I find this file (autodesk-forge-master.json)?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The [Learn Forge](https://learnforge.autodesk.io) website has a [Deployment](https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/deployment/) section that provides tips for deploying your application to various cloud hosting providers, incl. AWS, Azure, or Heroku.

However, if you're getting started with Forge (now called Autodesk Platform Services) development, I would suggest using one of the **PaaS** solutions such as [Heroku](https://heroku.com/) or [Fly.io](https://fly.io/).